# Using eqnarray (or similar) with exam class

Tags: align, exam

I'm trying to use `eqnarray` in my solutions to questions using the exam class:

```
    \begin{questions}
    \printanswers
    \question What is $10 - 3$?
    \begin{solution}
    \begin{eqnarray}
    10 - 3 &= 10 + (-3) \\
     &= 7 + 3 + (-3 )\\
     &= 7 + 0\\
     &= 7
    \end{eqnarray}
    \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
```

The result is not formatted properly:

[image: Eqnarray?]

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Do you need each line numbered separately?

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you, that was quick.  No, I don't need them numbered in any particular way.  Or indeed at all.

Comment: Put also `&` after `=`,i.e, `&=&`

Comment: Oh my goodness, that was simple thanks.  I feel a bit embarrassed now!  Thanks once again for your prompt reply.

Comment: You can also use the align environment (you will then have to use only one &, as in your mwe).

Comment: @Robert Arbon: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please rephrase your LaTeX-code into a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so people can try on their own.

Comment: @RobertArbon: I need to add an important note: eqnarray is [outdated!](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) Please replace it by align!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one "or similar" way, if you didn't want the numberings.  Also, it could be moved to any horizontal position.  I centered it by surrounding it with `\hfil`s:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \printanswers
    \question What is $10 - 3$?
    \begin{solution}
    \par\hfil\alignCenterstack{%
    10 - 3 =& 10 + (-3) \\
     =& 7 + 3 + (-3 )\\
     =& 7 + 0\\
     =& 7
    }\hfil
    \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One advantage of using this approach is that it puts the equation in a LaTeX "box", and thus there are limitless ways in which they can be moved around and manipulated on the page.  Here, for example, you could lay out two parallel solution strategies:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \printanswers
    \question What is $10 - 3$?
    \begin{solution}
    \par\hfil\alignCenterstack{%
    10 - 3 =& 10 + (-3) \\
     =& 7 + 3 + (-3 )\\
     =& 7 + 0\\
     =& 7
    }\hfil\alignCenterstack{%
    10 - 3 =& 10 + (-3) \\
     =& 10 + (7 - 10)\\
     =& 10 +(- 10) + 7\\
     =& 7
    }\hfil
    \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or even add commentary:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \printanswers
    \question What is $10 - 3$?
    \begin{solution}
    \par\hfil\alignCenterstack{%
    10 - 3 =& 10 + (-3) \\
     =& 7 + 3 + (-3 )\\
     =& 7 + 0\\
     =& 7
    }\hfil\stackinset{r}{3.7ex}{t}{-3.2ex}%
    {\color{red}\stackon{\scalebox{8}{$\times$}}{\mathrm{Don't~do~this!}}}%
    {\alignCenterstack{%
    10 - 3 =& 10 + (-3) \\
     =& 10 + (7 - 10)\\
     =& 10 +(- 10) + 7\\
     =& 7
    }}\hfil
    \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of a “Thank you” comment, you should give feedback clicking the 'up' arrow you can see above each answer's score. Once you’ve gathered 15 reputation points on this site, you’ll be able to [upvote answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) to contribute to this score.

Comment: Hi, thanks I just need two more reputation point to do that.

Comment: Can't these be made with envs instead? Making these as macro args is not particularly userfriendly (IMO)

Comment: @daleif There are already a number of environments for stacking math (which tend to occupy the full text width), but there were not, to my knowledge, the same breadth of macros, so I saw an opening to contribute.  I don't find the syntax off-putting (one just slaps braces around the content); however, one conundrum I haven't yet cracked is getting each equation numbered.  It's not easy since the result is a single LaTeX box.

Comment: @RobertArbon: now you have 18;).

Comment: @daleif I would just add that one of my key goals in developing `stackengine` and `tabstackengine` was to have the enclosing box exactly the size of the contents, and not stretch to the margins.  That way, much easier horizontal manipulations were possible, even to the extent of placing these things in-line.

Comment: Admirable, I just find the interface very unreadable plus your solution here require users to know about macros that are uncommon to most people (`\par` and `\hfil`)

Comment: @daleif  Of course, I could have used a blank line in lieu of the `\par`... but your point is taken. It is true that one must learn the language of horizontal manipulation (`\hfil`, `\hfill`, `\hspace`, `\kern`, and `\makebox[0pt]{...}`) if one hopes to get the most out of these techniques.

Comment: @daleif Final thoughts:  I had to use `\hfil` where I would normally use `\centering` because the latter does not work inside the `solution` environment (hah!).  Also note that `\stackMath` is not the package default. The origins of the packages were for stacking text and other items, not math (since there were already so many environmental ways of stacking math).  Stacking math with these packages was an adaptation of the original text-stacking idea.  But there are some cases where this boxed approach may prove easier than their environmental alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The probably best approach is to use `amsmath` and its environment `align`. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \printanswers
    \question What is $10 - 3$?
    \begin{solution}
    \begin{align}
    10 - 3 &= 10 + (-3) \\
           &= 7 + 3 + (-3 )\\
           &= 7 + 0\\
           &= 7
    \end{align}
    \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Remember that there is bad syntax allowed such as `eqnarray`. For more hints see [l2tabu](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf).

Comment: This also have a problem `=&` does not add space after the `=`. If you want to align on the right, use `={}&` instead.

Comment: the instructions for `align` clearly say to put the `&` *before* the `=` (or other relation); after the relation is set, it's too late to determine what the proper spacing should be.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, I thought it would not really matter, as everything in front of the `&` is placed relatively right of the alignment. You are right!